# How to get the executable path of a command line tool in Objective C (Foundation framework)?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to work out a way to identify the executable path of a command line tool in Objective C.

Hence, if the executable is /Applications/Utils/MyTool, then that method would return /Applications/Utils

I'm using the Foundation framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming that by `/Applications/Utils/MyTool`, you mean an application named "MyTool" in the "Utils" directory within the "Application" directory (which is actually the path `/Applications/Utils/MyTools.app`). In that case, you could get the directory in which the application resides (`/Applications/Utils`) with the following bit of code:

```
NSString *appParentDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

Comment: Correct! For some weird reason, I decided to assume NSBundle was under the Cocoa Framework. Thanks

Comment: It seems like `NSBundle` *should* be in AppKit, since command-line apps normally don't have bundles; but as you have obviously found out, a command-line app *can* have a bundle, so I guess that's why `NSBundle` is part of Foundation kit instead.

Answer (score 14):

Call me a purist - or a bundle-hater - *if you must*..  but I "like"

`NSString *myLittleCLIToolPath = NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift version of [@mipadi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2312136):

```swift
let appParentDirectory = Bundle.main.bundleURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
```

<sup>Documentation: `Bundle.main.bundleURL.deletingLastPathComponent()`</sup>

---

And of [@AlexGray's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000670/3939277):

```
let myLittleCliToolPath = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.first
```

<sup>Documentation: `ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.first`</sup>

Note that this one results in an optional string. It's likely that you got the path successfully, but not 100% guaranteed, so you could also use one of these as a backup (which also return optionals) if you have access to AppKit, or the aforementioned `Bundle` approach (which does not):

```
NSRunningApplication.current.bundleURL?.deletingLastPathComponent()
```

<sup>Documentation: `NSRunningApplication.current.bundleURL.deletingLastPathComponent()`</sup>

```
NSRunningApplication.current.executableURL?.deletingLastPathComponent()
```

<sup>Documentation: `NSRunningApplication.current.executableURL.deletingLastPathComponent()`</sup>