# Getting Current Directory in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, path

I am trying to get current directory, but its giving me path of DEBUG folder, how i can get the path of current directory. I am using the following code.

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *currentpath;

filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`currentDirectoryPath` returns the current working directory of the program. If you launch it from Xcode in Debug mode, the current directory of the program *is* the Debug directory.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get the path of the currently running xcode project?

Comment: You can set current directory manually in the scheme config -> arguments -> working directory

Answer (score 1):

Developing further on that. The current working directory and launch directory may be different! Take this example, the app is launched from the home directory (`~`).

```
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ehwczslxjxsxiob/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp -param value
```

```
NSString *p1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath];
// p1 = ~/Library/Containers/com.MyApp.beta/Data
NSString *p2 = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment][@"PWD"];
// p2 = ~
```

Depending on the situation you might want one or the other. In my case I want to provide a CLI which takes path arguments that may be relative to the current working directory in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

When getting paths for a service loaded via `launchd`, the paths can be very different.

```
NSLog(@"argv: %s", argv[0]);
NSLog(@"NSProcessInfo: %@", NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments[0]);
NSLog(@"currentDirectoryPath: %@", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath]);
NSLog(@"PWD: %@", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment][@"PWD"]);
```

Output:

```
argv: /Users/dev/.ioi/default-runtime-manager/default-runtime-manager
NSProcessInfo: /Users/dev/.ioi/default-runtime-manager/default-runtime-manager
currentDirectoryPath: /Users/dev/Library/Application Support/IOI/default-runtime-manager
PWD: (null)
```

- NSProcessInfo gives the location where the executable was found.
- currentDirectoryPath returns the WorkingDirectory specified in the launchd plist.

The answer to getting the executable path was found here: [StackOverflow: NSProcessInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000670/298545). The other paths were from: [@lupdidup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58059300/298545)