# File path to present dir. C++

Tags: c++

I am opening a ofstream in a small C++ program. The file is in the same directory as the program. It works fine when i open it with full file path. 
But open it with only "file.dat" doesn't work. 
So my question is: How do i declare the path to a file (or just the file) without including its path? Given that it is the same directory.

```
if(!readTheFile("/Users/mydirect/Desktop/DV1S5U4/DV1S5U4/timelog.dat")){
    cout << "Cant read timelog.dat" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you working in / executing from an IDE?  The working path sometimes gets set to another location messing that up.

Comment: I ma working in Xcode. Maybe thats why ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692489/getting-current-directory-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work. The problem you're having is that you need to set your working directory since I dunno where the default is.

```
Product > Edit Scheme > Info > Working Directory
```

There you can set it. Once you've set it and placed the .dat in the same folder it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

If the file really *is* in the current working directory you can use `"timelog.dat"` or, at least on POSIX systems, `"./timelog.dat"`. From the sounds of it, the current working directory seems different from what you think it is.

BTW, note that opening a file for *reading* with `std::ofstream` won't work too well: you might want to try `std::ifstream`. If the file was writable when you tried to open it with an `std::ofstream` it will now be empty unless you passed the argument `std::ios_base::app` when opening the file. ... and if the file is not writable, opening it with an `std::ofstream` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You write that your file is in "the same directory as the program" - it sounds like what you are after is not the current directory but the directory the executable came from. You can find that out on OS X using the function [`_NSGetExecutablePath()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dyld.3.html) - this just takes a buffer and buffer size and returns the path.