# Objective-C Relative File Path

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an xcode/objective-c project intended for use with the command line (not iOS or mac specifically). The project is in a folder called Prototype and in this folder I have a text file: data.txt. I am trying to make a method to return the contents of data.txt as an NSString. I have successfully done this with the following code:

```
+ (NSString *)loadTextFileToString:(NSString*)fileDest {
    NSString *filePath = @"/Users/John/Documents/Objective-C/Prototype/Prototype/data.txt"
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                     error:&error];
    return fileContent;
}
```

This approach works, but I would like to access the file with a relative path rather than an absolute path. For example, in Eclipse, I would use the path "src/data.txt". Is there a similar approach I can take to create a relative file path in xcode/objective-c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use a relative path, but the problem is that the current working directory may not be what you expect.

The current working directory is really a thing that's only relevant for working at a command-line shell. The user sets it how they want for their own convenience. They then invoke commands and pass paths as arguments, and the paths to the commands and the path arguments may be relative or absolute as they desire. Programs can't rely on the working directory being their own location nor any other specific location.

Certainly, when you run a program from Xcode, you can't rely on the working directory being any specific location.

If you want, you can set the current working directory using `-[NSFileManager changeCurrentDirectoryPath:]`, but then you destroy the ability to find files by relative paths that the user supplied. You can obtain the path of the directory containing your command-line tool using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the current working directory from this SO question.

[Getting Current Directory in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692489/getting-current-directory-in-objective-c)